# android app beginner for writing code for google Calendar API

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, google-calendar-api

I am a beginner at Android app design. I want to write a code to access the google calendar events and I have created authentication & authorization in https://console.cloud.google and downloaded the client_secret_...json then put it in the res and src folder in android. Because Google Documents hasn't step by step to build an android app then I follow the java sample of calendarQuickstart to create my Gradle and Mainactivity.java as below.

Gradle

```
plugins {

    id 'com.android.application'

}

android {

    compileSdk 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mycalendar1"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
// I use zulu8 


dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation files('libs/google-oauth-client-java6-1.32.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.32.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/google_http_client_gson-1.0.2.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.1'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```

Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.mycalendar1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;

import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;

import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;

import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;

import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;

import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;

import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;

import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;

import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Java Quickstart";
    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws
            IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
        //returns an authorized Credential object.
        return credential;
    }



    private static TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = findViewById(R.id.txt1);

        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        Calendar service = null;
        try {
            service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        

        Event event = null;
        try {
            event = service.events().get("***CalendarID", "***EventID").execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tv1.setText(event.getSummary().toString());
    }
}
```

only a text view tv1 in my activity_main.xml just shows the event summary.

when I run it, then I got a lot of errors.

Can anybody tell me how to use google calendar API in android? it bothers me so many days.

Thanks a lot.